# R Shiny app on AWS instance blocking API requests to Google Geocoding API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an R Shiny app hosted on AWS ec2 instance and part of the app is it makes API requests to Google geocoding API. This works fine locally but I have the app dockered and up on the instance and every time I try to make the API call from the app it crashes the server.

The requests are being made through a library called [`ggmap`](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/register_google.R) within the R Shiny app, to the Google geocoding api.

Any thoughts on where the origin of this could be?

I exposed ports 80 and 443 on both inbound and outbound for the security group for my instance. Still crashes.

My security group.

Inbound:

```
HTTP | TCP | 80 | 0.0.0.0/0
HTTP | TCP | 80 | ::/0
Custom TCP Rule | TCP | 4747 | 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule | TCP | 4747 | ::/0
SSH | TCP | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule | TCP | 3838 | 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule | TCP | 3838 | ::/0
HTTPS | TCP | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS | TCP | 443 | ::/0
```

Outbound:

```
HTTP | TCP | 80 | 0.0.0.0/0
HTTP | TCP | 80 | ::/0
All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS | TCP | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS | TCP | 443 | ::/0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes the server"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, what I meant is the instance shuts down and I have to reload the app. I think it's because the query is getting blocked, but I guess I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added my security group settings